# How to add down arrow on mouseover div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar. If I mouseover on any date field, one div popup will open its like a tooltip.

Here i want to add one down arrow like this,

[image]

How can I add this down arrow in div. I have an example.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/3592/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('hover', '.fc-day-number', function(){
  $('#cal-info').addClass('hide');
 var data = $(this).html();
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  $('#cal-info').css('left', offset.left);
  $('#cal-info').css('top', (offset.top - 40));
  $('#cal-info').html('information about: '+$(this).html()+'<br>Link to google: <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>');
 //p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
  $('#cal-info').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.tag{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:3px;
  max-height:60px;
  overflow:auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
<div class="tag hide" id="cal-info">

</div>
```

Comment: If setting the `.tag` element to `overflow: visible` is ok. Then you can do it with pseudo elements
http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/1/

Comment: @ToanLu thank you so much. Wrking fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your container is `position: fixed`, so I changed `overflow` to `visible`
and add the pseudo element to the `.tag` element to use the `border` property to create the triangle.

[jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/1/)

About the shape, you can check out [css-tricks post about making shape with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS:

```
.tag{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:3px;
  max-height:60px;
  overflow:auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1bAW.png");
}
```

This will set image to your div background. Instead of this url, You can set your local path.